# New Class for Account Number in Bank Account

Tags: java

I am doing a enhanced BankAccount class to see how abstraction and encapsulation enable evolutionary changes to the software.

Now I know the program I have up below isn't complete but I want to move the account number outside of the class.
For moving the account number outside of the class I don't get if that means I have to create a totally new class. I know a program can have more than one class per java file but only one can be public, I just don't know if I truly need it. should I make the new class for my account number private? And if I do can I just throw it in at the end? I don't know how to go about this! Im sorry I ask my professor constantly but he bounces around the topic and never answers my questions about classes!

I'm new to java so don't give me the entire code corrected! I would like to learn

Here is the program the teacher provided me (incomplete):

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Bank Account Class
 * @author Morgan
 * @version 1.1
 *
 */
public class BankAccounts {

//data members
private double balance;    // account balance
private int acctNum;    // account number
private byte acctType;    // types of account: 1 for Checking; 2 for savings
private int currentNumberOfTransactions;    // current number of transactions per month
private double perTransactionFlatFee;    // charge per transaction - depends on type of account

private static Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());    //create random number generate object

private final static int CHECKING_MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRANSACTIONS_PER_MONTH = 5;
private final static int SAVINGS_MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRANSACTIONS_PER_MONTH = 2;

/**
 * default constructor - initializes account balance and account number
 */
private BankAccounts(){
    balance = 0.0;        // initialize account balance

    // generate random number accordingly and assign to account number
    acctNum = generator.nextInt(1000) + 9999;    
    currentNumberOfTransactions = 0;    // initialize 
    perTransactionFlatFee = 0.0;        // initialize    
}

/**
 * constructor with current balance; initialize account number
 * @param balance    initial account balance
 * @param type        type of account (1 for Checking; 2 for Savings)
 */
    public BankAccounts(double balance, byte type, int acctNum?){
        this();    // use default constructor

        this.balance = balance;    // set initial balance
        acctType = type;        // set account type

        switch (type){
        case 1:    perTransactionFlatFee = 0.10; break;
        case 2: perTransactionFlatFee = 0.20; break;
        }
    }

/**
 * constructor with account number; initialize balance
 * @param type    type of account (1 for Checking; 2 for Savings)
 */
    public BankAccounts(byte type){
        this();    // use default constructor

        acctType = type;        // set account type

        switch (type){
        case 1:    perTransactionFlatFee = 0.10; break;
        case 2: perTransactionFlatFee = 0.20; break;
        }

    }


/**
 * getter to return current balance        
 * @return    current account balance
 */
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

/**
 * deposit into account
 * @param amount    amount to deposit; not more than 10,000
 * @return            true or false
 */
public void deposit(double amount){
    // deposit amount - deduct per transaction fee based on type of account

}

/**
 * withdraw from account
 * @param amount    amount to withdraw; not more than 10,000
 * @return            true or false
 */
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    // withdraw amount - deduct per transaction fee based on type of account

}


private String getAcctType() {
    String ret = "";

    switch(acctType){
    case 1: ret = "Checking"; break;
    case 2: ret =  "Savings"; break;
    }

    return ret;
}

/**
 * Resets the current number of transactions to 0
 * @param bankAccount    Account to reset current number of transactions
 */

public static void reSetAccount(BankAccounts bankAccount){
    bankAccount.currentNumberOfTransactions = 0;
}

/**
 * Deducts the applicable monthly charges from the account balance.
 *             May lead to negative balance.
 * @param bankAccount    Account to apply the monthly charge
 * @param chargeAmt        Amount to charge if maximum allowable transactions have been exceeded
 */

public static void deductMonthlyCharges(BankAccounts bankAccount, double chargeAmt){
   // deduct from balance the chargeAmt if applicable maximum allowable transactions have been exceeded
        balance = balance - chargeAmt


    // reset current number of transactions
        //add my code here


    System.out.println("\n\nCharges applied successfully.");
}

/**
 * Prints an account information - Account number, type, balance, and current number of transactions
 */
public void print(){
    System.out.println("\n\nAccount Number: " + acctNum  + "\nAccount Type: " + getAcctType() + 
                "\nBalance: " + balance + "\nCurrent Number of Transactions: " + currentNumberOfTransactions);
}



}
```

Comment: An additional topic for consideration here is composition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition. You currently have a `primitive` representation of an account number. By introducing a class (object) to represent the data, you are migrating to Object Oriented Programming which involves the other topics you stated: encapsulation, abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, I would suggest to make `AccountNumber` a static nested class of `BankAccount` -

```
public class BankAccounts {  

    public static class AccountNumber {
        // your class declaration
    }

    // other methods/properties
}
```

If objects of any other class needs access to your `AccountNumber` instances, then you can make it public. If this is not the case, then you can make it private. In that way, only `BankAccounts` members will be able to instantiate `AccountNumber` objects.

From your example program, your account number seems very simple (just an `int`). For something this simple, creating a separate class is overkill.

Comment: ok that makes sense! but when i have to make a the new class for the account number, does that mean when i create the number generator to create the account number (found in private BankAccounts ()) i move it into that new class I made or do I keep it there?

Comment: @Morgan: Yup, you also move the account number generation  logic into the new class. Whenever someone creates an instance of `AccountNumber`, this code will generate an account number using that logic. Better yet, you could declare a private method in that new class called `generate`, which you can call from the constructor to generate your account number for you.

Comment: would the generate method be void?

Comment: @Morgan: No, since it will generate and return your account number. If you choose to use `int` for that, it will have a return type of `int`. If it is a string, then return type will be `String`, and so on.